# iOs register for notifications from camera roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

Is there a way to register for notifications when user takes a picture or video which are added to the camera roll?
I know you can register for Contacts notifications, but I need to know if user has added image or video to the camera roll.
I see the Google+ claim they upload your image "instantly" after you take a picture but I wonder if they just run in the assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
loop in the thread all the time...

Answer (score 3):

ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification

Sent when the contents of the assets library have changed from under the app that is using the data.

From [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Will I get this notification even if my app is in the background or only when user actually puts the app in the foreground?

Comment: You will receive it when app will come to foreground. To work in background you have three options http://stackoverflow.com/a/4928363/88198

Comment: Then how google+ claim to upload your photo instantly when you take a picture without the need to go into the foreground?

Comment: Maybe tracks users location