# MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange in background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, mpmediaplayercontroller

Is there a way to get the `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange` notification while the app is in the background?

I have an app that needs to be able to pause the music once a song has ended while in the background or when the screen is locked. I'm using a [systemMusicPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624179-systemmusicplayer) to play the music.

I've tried adding the audio background capability and including a call to `beginBackgroundTask` in my `applicationDidEnterBackground` but that doesn't work for extended periods of time.

Comment: how about use a observer ?

Comment: @KennyVB, would that be able to work for an indefinite amount of time in either the background or while the phone is locked?

Comment: it will work until you stop observing...
you can put a observer when it starts playing and stop it when it's finished så it dont break your app

Comment: I don't think that will work since that's pretty much what I am trying to do with `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange`. Also have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928207/receiving-notifications-with-app-in-background-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in background, your app might be killed at any time, so you do not want to depend on acting in background.

How I understood, what you want to achieve is that when your app goes to background, the currently playing music goes on but stops after the currently playing song finished.

`MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()` is playing a queue of songs ("Playlist"). So I would try to manipulate this `queue` in `applicationWillResignActive()` to not have a song after the currently playing one .

I did not test this and I am not sure whether or not this is possible through public API.

Comment: Are you saying that when the app goes to the background (or device locks) to pause/stop the music? And to have it so that the app has to stay open until it the music finishes? And that there is no way to do it the way described in the question (which is ok if that's the case)?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: This doesn't help. My app needs to play a certain amount of songs and then stop when they're done. I want to be able to get notifications when the app is in the background so that it knows when to stop.

Comment: I understood. But as your approach is not possible, I was trying to point you to a another direction to work around.

Comment: It may have taken me a year to mark this as correct, but you were right - it was not possible in the end.